# Making Div relative to other content on a page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a very minor issue but i have been trying to fix it for few hours with no luck at all. I have a simple page that uses bootstrap. Following is the screenshot.

[image]

In this screenshot, I had my browser window maximized. As you can see the search bar is centered well and the names of 3 favorite players in the bottom are not. Now when i make the browser window size half of it. This is what i see.

[image]

Now the search bar no longer is center and the names of favorite players are centered. This is definitely not responsive as it should be.

**Problem**
I have identified two issues. One is that the search bar is somehow not releative and the names of the players are not. So I tried various css by making its div to absolute and relative and messed around with padding but no luck.

I am sure i am missing something here and this might be a stupid question but it would help me because i have been stuck on this for long while now.

I have uploaded my code on [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/zYFA6mqMO1)

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row bg-success" style="background-color: #f6f5f1;padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-1">
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <div id="searchPage-small-title">NBA</div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-title">Player Portal</div>
    </div>
  </div>



<!--   <div class="row">
 -->    <div class="col-lg-4">  
        <div class="searchPage-box text-left">         
            <form role="form" class="form-inline" ng-submit="submit()">           
              <div class="form-group">             
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="searchPage-input" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search Player" typeahead="sponsor as label(sponsor) for sponsor in sponsorList
                          | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:12" typeahead-editable="true" typeahead-min-length="2" required="" name="sponsorName">
                    </div>      
                  <div class="col-md-1">      
                  <!-- using Bootstrap default for button -->

                  </div>                 
                </div>
            </div>  
          </form> 
        </div>      
      </div>
   <!--  </div>  -->












</div>


  <div class="row bg-warning" style="background-color: #eeede7; padding-bottom:100px;">

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-1">
     </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-favorites-title" class="row">FAVORITES</div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>

      <!-- this favorites are hard-coded for now for purposes of demo -->
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Jordan
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Lebron
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Curry
      </div>

    </div>



  </div>






</div>
```

I highly appreciate all suggestions and approaches.

Comment: You are not using the power of Bootstrap in the right way

Comment: I suggest you must read and understand bootstrap grid.  With this you can make a good looking web page

Answer (score 2):

Not at my computer now, so I will have to answer more fully in a bit, but one thing that jumps out to me: instead of having empty divs with bootstrap columns, use offsets; for example, `col-lg-offset-1`.

EDIT:  Expanding my answer.

Here is a [link to my forked version of your Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kalendubrick/RwOnSRz0jp), showing my changes.  The following is a small portion of the bootply:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div id="searchPage-small-title">NBA</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
    <div id="searchPage-title">Player Portal</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yuri's answer does a pretty good job of explaining the issues you're coming up against.  If you're going to use Bootstrap, in general, you need to *only* use Bootstrap's layout classes to set your layout - adding custom `positions` and other things like that can really mess with the page, as you've seen.

I won't go into a detailed explanation of the changes I made, in the hopes that you can have a look and figure out what makes it work, but I do have some notes:

First, rather than `lg`, it's better to define at least an `xs` behavior, and work your way up to bigger screens.  By only defining `col-lg-x` classes for most of your items, you're not defining a responsive layout for viewports below that size.

Second, there were a couple places where you had `row` classes nested directly inside other `row` classes.  This can also cause issues.  The intended method of use is

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-x">
     <!-- if you need to define another grid inside the above div,
          start another row -->
     <div class="row">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Third, as I mentioned in my initial response, rather than adding empty divs with column classes (which will be collapsed automatically), use `col-{size}-offset-x` classes on the first div in the row (in addition to the regular `col-{size}-x` class).  Also, related to alignment: rather than using `text-align: center`, you can just add bootstrap's `text-center` class to what you want to center.

The only issue in my version is that the favorites box overlap on a small screen - this is because of their defined size.  I'll leave that to you to fix.

I hope this answer helped you, and please let me know if you have any questions about my answer.

Comment: I would appreciate your input

Comment: @user1010101 I apologize, my day has been busier than I expected.  I will do my best to expand on my answer later today sometime.

Comment: Hi did you have any chance to look

Comment: @user1010101 Sorry again, busy weekend.  I've posted my updated and expanded answer.

Comment: I notice when i make the screen smaller the search bar gets thrown to right or left side

Comment: It appears that the bootply has reverted to the state it was in when I first forked it from yours, which is very irritating.  I will try to recreate it in a codepen when I am able... it may be a couple days.

Answer (score 2):

***do not copy, learn how it works by looking at this example***

This absolute not the correct way but give you a small idea!

Any questions ?? comment away! :)

```css
#searchPage-small-title {
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}
#searchPage-title {
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: center;
}
.searchPage-box {
  text-align: center;
}
.searchPage-input {
  width: 80%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-color: rgba(192, 189, 178, 1);
  height: 59px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-indent: 32px;
}
.fa-star {
  color: rgba(220, 118, 28, 1);
}
#searchPage-favorites-title {
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.searchPage-favorites-item {
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 800;
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 115px;
  width: 140px;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--row I-->
  <div class="row bg-success" style="background-color: #f6f5f1;padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-small-title">NBA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--row II-->
  <div class="row bg-success" style="background-color: #f6f5f1;padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-title">Player Portal</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- row III -->
  <div class="row" style="background-color: #eeede7; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="searchPage-box">
        <form role="form" class="form" ng-submit="submit()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="searchPage-input" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search Player" typeahead="sponsor as label(sponsor) for sponsor in sponsorList
                          | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:12" typeahead-editable="true" typeahead-min-length="2" required="" name="sponsorName">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- row IV -->
  <div class="row bg-warning" style="background-color: #eeede7; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-favorites-title">FAVORITES</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- row V -->
  <div class="row" style="background-color: #eeede7; padding-bottom:100px; text-align: center;">
    <div class="col-lg-4 searchPage-favorites-item">
      <i class="fa fa-star">Jordan</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 searchPage-favorites-item">
      <i class="fa fa-star">Lebron</i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 searchPage-favorites-item">
      <i class="fa fa-star">Curry</i>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**Edit:**

The following div have the class col-lg-4 meaning the width if the available space will be 33,333333%. Also the first child of this div has `text-left` class. If you adjust `col-lg-4` to `col-lg-12` and the first child with `text-left` to `text-center` you will have the desire result.

**Edit:**
and alter the next css:

```
.searchPage-box {
    /* padding-left: 590px; remove */
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

(from [http://www.bootply.com/zYFA6mqMO1](http://www.bootply.com/zYFA6mqMO1#))

```
<div class="col-lg-4">  
        <div class="searchPage-box text-left">         
            <form role="form" class="form-inline" ng-submit="submit()">           
              <div class="form-group">             
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="searchPage-input" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search Player" typeahead="sponsor as label(sponsor) for sponsor in sponsorList
                          | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:12" typeahead-editable="true" typeahead-min-length="2" required="" name="sponsorName">
                    </div>      
                  <div class="col-md-1">      
                  <!-- using Bootstrap default for button -->

                  </div>                 
                </div>
            </div>  
          </form> 
        </div>      
      </div>
```

Comment: This completely changes my page , I am more confused.

Comment: that is why i said... 'do not copy, learn how it works by looking at this example'

Comment: I understand the concept of row and column but i am not sure what i did wrong in my code, I don't have as many rows as you but I don't need to.

Comment: Okeay, have you this page online ? do you have a link ?

Comment: @user1010101 what browser do you use ?

Comment: I am using chrome browswer

Comment: notice what happens when you make your browser screen smaller, you will see that search bar goes towards right side and does not center it self like a responsive design would expect to do so. This is same as issue i was having before

Comment: have you changed both col-lg-4 ?? because if i applies my change 'it works'

Comment: I aplogize yes it works now! Do i need to do the same thing to align the favorite players in the bottom?

Comment: I'll take a look. No need to apologize ;)

Answer (score 0):

Heres what you should note:

```
.searchPage-box {padding-left: 590px}
```

Using padding-left and setting pixels is a bad idea, because when the screen size does change, pixels don't auto change. So if you want to center it, try this:

```
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
display: block !important;
width: 30% !important;
```

Those go under

```
.searchPage-box
```

Hope I helped :)

Comment: this pushes it to the left

Comment: Did you remove padding-left: 590px?

Comment: yes i did, try it in the BOOTPLY link you will see what i mean, are you seeing it work perfectly on your browser?

Comment: Yeah I am, it does work , even when I move my browser around.

Comment: are you sure? can you share FIDDLE? very strange

Answer (score 0):

Your div around the search bar this one:
    
uses your css class searchPage-box, that one is using padding left 590px

```
.searchPage-box {
  padding-left: 590px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

This cause 590px to the left of the search bar to be unused.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row bg-success" style="background-color: #f6f5f1;padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1">
        <div id="searchPage-small-title">NBA</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
    </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-title">Player Portal</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- change in code is here -->

    **<div class="row">  
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-1 text-left">**


            <form role="form" class="form-inline" ng-submit="submit()">           
              <div class="form-group">             
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <input type="text" class="searchPage-input" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search Player" typeahead="sponsor as label(sponsor) for sponsor in sponsorList
                          | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:12" typeahead-editable="true" typeahead-min-length="2" required="" name="sponsorName">
                    </div>      
                  <div class="col-md-1">      
                  <!-- using Bootstrap default for button -->

                  </div>                 
                </div>
            </div>  
          </form> 
        </div>      
      </div>
   <!--  </div>  -->
</div>


  <div class="row bg-warning" style="background-color: #eeede7; padding-bottom:100px;">

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-1">
     </div> 
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <div id="searchPage-favorites-title" class="row">FAVORITES</div>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
      </div>

      <!-- this favorites are hard-coded for now for purposes of demo -->
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Jordan
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Lebron
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        Curry
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using col-sm-2 on the footer div but you lose responsive behaviour when you set `width:140px` in `.searchPage-favorites-item`.
Remove that rule and `.col-sm-4` and use `.col-sm-offset-3` instead:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 searchPage-favorites-item">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    Jordan
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    Lebron
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item">
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    Curry
</div>
```

or better

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 searchPage-favorites-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Jordan</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Lebron</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 searchPage-favorites-item"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Curry</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For what concerns your form, if you want to have it centered and you have 1 column at end row, you have to have one at the beginning too (or you set offset-1)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
        <input class="searchPage-input" autocomplete="off" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search Player" typeahead="sponsor as label(sponsor) for sponsor in sponsorList
                          | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:12" typeahead-editable="true" typeahead-min-length="2" required="" name="sponsorName" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <!-- using Bootstrap default for button -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Or just use .col-lg-12 on it

Remember: with bootstrap you rarely have to deal with layout positioning in your custom css, since you can obtain a lot just using its classes. You should just style colors, shadows, text and things like these

Comment: The search bar still is not aligned